# Array modifier leaves gaps when applied

Tags: modifiers

The gaps only occur when I apply the modifier. Checking the "merge" doesn't seem to fix it at all either. (It's unchecked in the image because I prefer not to tick it due to the hole in the middle being deformed, same problem either way.)

[image: before applying:]

[image: after applying:]

Comment: Hello could you please share the object itself? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: It would have been good if you had also shared an image of the wheel without the _Array_ modifier enabled. And maybe the angle of the object you're using for the _Object Offset_? Because somehow this looks like it's not matching. But uploading the file is a good idea, too.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVIGT.png ?

Comment: Nevermind, seems like I had to apply the mirror modifier first. There's no gaps anymore. Thanks to @Gorgious for pointing out the error that I completely ignored, I'm blind lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying the modifiers in order might have solved the issue, but still I would wonder if everything was modeled accurately. So, although your problem is solved, please take a look at the following image: It's not so clearly visible on all "spokes", but especially the two on the bottom left are clearly off-enter if you would model it with a 72° degree angle between each of them (which would result in 360° for all 5). So either there was some inaccuracy in the mesh before the array or you did not rotate them exactly 72°. Just in case you run into issues in the future as well and changing the order of applying modifiers does not help.

[image: inaccurate array]

Comment: Very helpful indeed! I didn't actually try to rotate them exactly 72 degrees, but tried my best to do it as accurate as possible. I'm kind of new to Blender and there's a ton of helpful methods and tools that I'm not aware of yet. Thanks a ton!